# SQL : Between 'One table many columns' and 'Multiple table many time query'

Tags: sql

My website has a post system, and there are 3 types of posts

1. Picture
2. Video
3. Repost

I use 4 tables to manage this data

1. post
2. picture
3. video
4. repost

Every picture, video, repost that is posted to the site will have one post row to keep likecount, commentcount , etc.

I have to query how many times comments are liked or something is deleted.

I want to know that between

1. One table, many columns, many null rows, one time query
2. Multiple tables, less null rows, many times query

Which one is better and faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"which one is better and faster?"

I don't think either option is better *and* faster - one table is normally faster, multiple tables is 'better' in that it's easier to maintain and doesn't lead to duplicate data.  If speed of retrieval is your main concern then one table can be justified, otherwise I'd stick with normalization
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Even with multiple tables, good indexes can make a huge difference to retrieval speed, and as others have said it might be worth considering a view/stored procedure to bring the data together

Comment: Thank you now i've my answer!

Answer (score 3):

As is common with these types of questions, this answer is "it depends."

I would suggest that you experiment with creating a VIEW of your data that compiles your 4 tables into a single-row, multi-column resultset.  You can even index this view and, if needed, `INSERT INTO` the view.  This should give you a good sense of how you want to model your data.

On the one extreme you have:

- Multiple tables, requiring multiple indexes (if you want to keep everything peppy, as if it were one row) will require more storage space.
- But that also means you can store your data tables in different file groups and storage areas so your larger, more expensive binary data doesn't eat up your more expensive drive space.

And on the other extreme you have:
* One table that requires no joins and has all it needs right there
* But has the burden of being stored in one file file group and growing uncontrollably as you add more post types

And somewhere in the middle, you have (indexed) views.

Answer (score 2):

There is no simple answer to this.

If you split data over many tables, then you need to write more complex SQL but the database admin can put each table on a different disk so *loading* the data will be faster.

Search performance is not influenced by this because indexes can be put on different disks.

So this depends on the database architecture, the amount of data, the indexes and how they are assigned to disks and whether the database optimizer will chose the correct strategy.

Comment: i think i have to learn more abt database! Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

with a single table, you eliminate the overhead of JOINs, so it would probably be faster.

However, depending on your setup, you can probably use a View or Stored Procedure to pull the data together from the different tables. These would increase the efficiency of the JOINs, since the query execution plan can be cached/optimized